# jQuery syntax for working with XML in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I was wondering whether you know of any libraries that provide a jquery like interface for working with XML in C#. A Google search didn't turn up anything useful, so I'm turning to you.

Comment: Use LINQ to XML.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "a jquery like interface" here? LINQ to XML is a fantastic XML API, but I don't know whether or not it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, LINQ to XML is the way to go.

Start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb387061.aspx) in the MSDN documentation.